# How to add text to paths

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree - although I've got no errors in the console to help me out.

I've got this block of code:

```
var path = svg.data([json]).selectAll("path")
    .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("display", function(d) {
        return d.depth ? null : "none";
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
    })
    .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .each(stash);

//>>this section functions ok
path.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name + ": " + d.amount;
    });

//>>this section throws no errors but "foo" does not appear
path.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return "foo";
    })
    .style("stroke", "#3b5998")
    .style("fill", "#3b5998");
```

The code snippet beginning `path.append("title")...` works ok but the final snippet beginning `path.append("text")...` adds the text foo to the html but it is not visible on the webpage - why is it not visible and how do I add labels?

This is part of this visual:

http://plnkr.co/edit/q9ODd5?p=preview

Comment: For a really in-depth tutorial covering all this you might want to have a look into [*"Placing Texts on Arcs with D3.js"*](http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs.html). It's worth the time!

Comment: @altocumulus great link - thank you....look!!! http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/V4Zr16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text` cannot be nested with a `path`. You'll need to add it to the `svg` instead. Additionally, you'll want to position the text in some way:

```
  svg.append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
        return "foo";
    })
    .attr("x", function(){ return 0 })
    .attr("y", function(){ return 0 })
    .style("stroke", "#3b5998")
    .style("fill", "#3b5998");
```

Comment: thanks for the help - I added code below which distributes the labels to each arc

Answer (score 1):

The working code ended as the following:

```
var path = svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theArc")
    .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "theArc")   //<<<<<<<<<<new 
    .attr("id", function(d,i) { return "theArc_"+i; }) //Give each slice a unique ID //<<<<<<<<<<new jq
    .attr("display", function(d) {
        return d.depth ? null : "none";
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("stroke", "#fff")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
    })
    .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .each(stash);

path
    .append("title") //mouseover title showing the figures
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name + ": " + d.amount;
    });

svg.data([json]).selectAll(".theTxts")
    .data(partition.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "theTxts")
    .attr("dx", 10)   //Move the text from the start angle of the arc
    .attr("dy", 18) //Move the text down
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
        return "#theArc_" + i;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    })
    .style("stroke", "#3b5998")
    .style("fill", "#3b5998");
```